# sharing json between controllers with angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a rather big Json object that I am receiving via $http that I want to share between 2 controllers. To give you an idea - both controllers share the parent most array (marked as levels), and then within the levels there are key:values with nested arrays ( 2 of them) and each controller uses and edits them separately. I am trying to consolidate this as much as possible so I thought if i could control 1 json between 2 controllers this would work.

I want to be able to edits each sub array and push back to the server as a whole, but before I attempt this step I would like to be sure something like this is even possible. I have tried using a factory and service to no avail. I am slo curious if I can do this and I bring in the array - is it 2 way binded? The first controller should be able to add more levels, and the second one can add to them in a differen't way the first one can't. If I were to bring in the json and share it between controllers and added a level on the first one, would it show on the second?

I have been banging my head against this for a while now, so any insight or direction would be very appreciated. Thanks!!

I took a stab at what the json might look like (forgive me if the syntax is off)-

```
{
"level1": {
 "form": {
    "form1": "sample1",
    "form2": "sample2",
    "form3": 500,
    "form4": 500
}
"sublevels": {
    "subL":  ["1", "2", "3"],
    "help1": "main_window",
    "help2": 500
}},
"level2": {
 "form": {
    "form1": "sample1",
    "form2": "sample2",
    "form3": 500,
    "form4": 500
}
"sublevels": {
    "subL":  ["1", "2", "3"],
    "help1": "main_window",
    "help2": 500
}

}
```

}

so both controllers would build off the levels, something like "level in levels" ng-repeat type scenario, but controller 1 would use the "Form" key, and controller 2 would use the "subevels" keys. they would be able to edit those sections and post the whole sting back to the server for a save. I don't have much else because the factories/services I Tried to setup didn't seem to work at all. Thanks!

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: I don't have anything working so I've tried to represent the json to make it more clear. I am just wondering if/how something like this would be possible. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put it on service, but a simpler way is use rootscope, or create a parent controller common for both of your controllers